# Trying to compile cross-platform C++ code.Undefined reference to C function

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-errors

I used the C-library RS232 in my C++ code to control an Arduino Uno board. In my main.cpp, I got:

```
#include "rs232.h"
```

because in the rs232.h header file, they already have:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

In one folder, I have:
main.cpp
rs232.h
rs232.c
stdafx.h
stdafx.cpp

and I use cygwin to compile so that the code could be used for Linux:

```
g++ main.cpp
```

but I got errors with "...undefined reference to '_OpenComport'" and similar to all C functions that I called from my main.cpp.

Can anyone tell me how to include the C header file in C++? Or is it that I used the wrong command for g++?

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass all source files to the compiler, like so

```
g++ -o demo.exe main.cpp rs232.c stdafx.cpp
```

Alternatively, compile parts into a library, and separate compile and link steps.

Comment: Thanks...it works. So simple yet so elusive to a Windows-centric person.

Comment: in Windows if you would try to compile only main.cpp you'd get exactly same error.

Comment: Well I wrote the code using Visual Studio and I haven't had to make a port to Linux until now.